# Primos, pares e impares en Java

Tags: java, jar

Quiero un programa que muestre pida numeros al usuario hasta que ingrese un "0" o un número negativo, cuando esto ocurra, el programa debe mostrar:
1.-Cuántos numeros se ingresarón
2.Cuántos son primos
3.-Cuantos son pares
4.- Cuantos son impares.

He realizado el codigo para los casos 2,3, y 4. ¿Puedo unir el codigo que ya tengo de algúna manera? 
Honestamente no tengo idea de que necesito o por donde proceder, pues es mi primer curso de Java.
¿Que deberia aprender para poder resolver esto?

Tengo codigo para los números primos :

```
package nprimo;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nprimo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temp;
        boolean isPrime=true;
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i=2;i<=num/2;i++)
        {
            temp=num%i;
            if (temp==0)
            {
                isPrime=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime)
            System.out.println(num +"Es un numero primo :) ");
        else 
            System.out.println(num +"No es un número primo :( ");
    }
}
```

y el codigo para saber si el número es par o impar.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int n;
String m="";
System.out.println("*Determinarn numero es par o impar*");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("ingreseumero");
Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
n=teclado.nextInt();
if(n%2==0)
m="es par";
else
m="es impar";
System.out.println("elro "+n+" "+m);
}
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Nada mas estas validando el numero una sola vez, necesitas agregar un ciclo while para estar pidiendo numeros al usuario hasta que capture 0 o menor y que de ahi salga el ciclo while. Ademas necesitas agregar un contador para ver cuantas veces el usuario capturo un numero.

Comment: Podrias construir un Objeto(Clase) contador para llevar la cantidad de numeros y las condiciones que cumples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno, puedes tener 'IsPrimo', 'IsPar', 'IsImpar', como tres funciones booleanas (que devuelvan 'true' o 'false' como resultado). Entonces, para contar la cantidad de números que ingresas, puedes tener un while con un contador dentro... Mientras que para contar si es par, impar o primo, puedes tener diferentes contadores que aumente si se cumple la condición específica. Si es primo, aumentará el contador de número primo, y así sucesivamente.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int contador = 0, contadorPrimo =0, contadorPar = 0;
        int contadorImpar = 0, n = 0;

        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in); 
        //Declaro el contador aqui, para no hacerlo cada vez que empiece el                 
         //ciclo

        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese un numero: "); 
            n=teclado.nextInt();

            if (isPrimo(n)){
                contadorPrimo++;
            } else if (isImpar(n)){ 
                contadorImpar++; 
            }else if (isPar(n)){
                contadorPar++;
            }
            contador ++; 
        }while(n>0); 
        System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros: " +contador); 
        System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros primos: " + contadorPrimo);
        System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros pares: " + contadorPar);
        System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros impares: " + contadorImpar);
    }


    public static boolean isPrimo(int num){
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i=2;i<=num/2;i++)
        {
            temp=num%i;
            if (temp==0)
            {
              return false; 
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isImpar(int num) { 
        if(num%2==0){
            return false;
        }else 
            return true; 
    }

    public static boolean isPar(int num) { 
        if(num%2==0){
            return true;
        }else 
            return false; 
        }
```

}

Esos if's y else if's llaman a las funciones y le mandan como parámetro 'n' (el núumero que ingresaste. Si el resultado que devuelven es 'true' entonces, se cumplirá la sentencia en el if.

[image: Aquí una imagen de prueba:]

No sé si quieres que cuente al '0' o al número negativo como un número, de ser así, entonces debes cambiar estos dos:

```
     System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros: " + (contador-1)); 
     System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros primos: " + (contadorPrimo-1));
```

El '1' que le restas al contador de números, es el '0' que pones para salir del do while. Y en el caso de 'contadorPrimo' es porque, en este caso, el 0 está siendo considerado un número primo.

Comment: Hola Adalgisa. No quiero pisar tu respuesta. Pero ahi no definiste IsPrimo como una clase.. en realidad no lo definiste ni como una funcion, si no como un booleano. no se si era tu intencion, pero le vas a causar mas confusion a quien pregunta. Si sabes como corregirla, hazlo. Si no deberemos votar tu respuesta como negativa porque no contesta la pregunta.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero la función podría retornar un booleano y así serviría... La agregaré a la respuesta y ya. Soy nueva, no sabía que debía dar la respuesta con todo explícito...

Comment: ok.. mira [answer] para ver como hacer una respuesta completa.. la idea es que quien pregunta no tenga que pedir aclaraciones. Si tenes dudas con tu respuesta, puedes pedir tu las aclaraciones que necesites.Y bienvenida!

Comment: Está bien, gracias!

Comment: Intente hacerlo usando diferentes clases, como mencionó antes de editar su respuesta, sin embargo creo que si me resultó un poco más complejo, aunque debo reconocer que aprendí un uso más "profundizado" para dichas clases.  GRACIAS.

Answer (score 0):

Considero que la respuesta de @Adalgisa Ferrer es valida, a continuación presento una variación a la respuesta dada por @Adalgisa Ferrer

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContarNumeros {
public static void main (String [] args){
    int contador = 0, contadorPrimo =0, contadorPar = 0;
    int contadorImpar = 0, n = 0;

    Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in); 
    //Declaro el contador aqui, para no hacerlo cada vez que empiece el                 
     //ciclo

    do{
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero: "); 
        n=teclado.nextInt();

        if (isPar(n)){
            contadorPar++;
            if(n == 2){
                contadorPrimo++;
            }
        } else{ 
            contadorImpar++;
            if(n != 1 && isPrimo(n)){
                contadorPrimo++;
            }
        }
        contador ++; 
    }while(n>0); 
    System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros: " +contador); 
    System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros primos: " + contadorPrimo);
    System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros pares: " + contadorPar);
    System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros impares: " + contadorImpar);
}

public static boolean isPrimo(int num){
    boolean primo = true;
    int maxvalue = (int)(Math.sqrt(num));
    for (int i=3; i <= maxvalue; i = i+2)
    {

        if (num%i == 0)
        {
          primo = false;
          break;
        }
    }
    return primo;
}

public static boolean isPar(int num) { 
    boolean par = true;
    if(num%2 != 0){
        par = false;
    }
    return par;
}
}
```

Los cambios son los siguientes:

1. Solo dejamos el metodo que valida si es un número par, en caso de no ser par es impar.
2. Si es par, validamos si es el numero 2, si es así, aumentamos en 1 el contador de números primos.
3. La validación de si es un primo solo la realizamos si el número es impar y diferente a 1.
4. En el método de `isPrimo(n)` disminuimos el rango de validación hasta la raiz cuadrada de `n` iniciando desde el número `3` y solo validamos con números impares.
5. Si existe un divisor impar para el número `n` entonces `n` no es primo y  salimos del cilclo.