# Llenar un vector de n posiciones con números primos

Tags: java

Tengo que llenar un vector de `n` posiciones con números primos, pero no me sale nada mi pc se bloqueo y lo intenté en otro y me tocó cancelar el proceso. Les dejo mi código para que me ayuden a corregirlo.

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numerosPrimos(3);
    }

    public static void numerosPrimos(int n) {
        int v[] = new int[n];
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            while (i <= n) {
                if (b % 2 != 0) {
                    v[i] = b;
                    b++;
                } else {
                    b++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + v[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Ya corregí el código sería así:

```
public static void numerosPrimos(int n) {
    int v[] = new int[n];
    int b = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        while (i != n) {
            if (b % 2 != 0) {
                v[i] = b;
                i++;
                b++;
            } else {
                b++;
            }
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + v[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: i++ adentro del mismo for que lo suma?? que es lo que no hace, por el codigo parece no hacer nada potable

Comment: Aca dejo una entrada que te puede ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92452/primos-pares-e-impares-en-java/92909#92909

Answer (score 1):

Te ayudo un poco, yo lo haria asi:

```
public static void numerosPrimos(int n) {
    int v[] = new int[n];
    int posicion=0;

    //hallando un numero primo
    int divisibles;
    for(int i=0;posicion<n;i++){ //no sale de este for sino esta lleno el vector
        divisibles=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){ // aqui este for, recorre todos los numeros detras de el
            if(i%j==0){ //los numero primos solo son divisible por 1 y por ellos mismo
                divisibles++;
            }
        }
        if(divisibles==2){ //si es divisible por el y por 1 entrara
            v[posicion]=i; // guardo numero el en vector
            posicion++; // aumento una posicion para el sgte numero
        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("" + v[i]);
    }
}
```

se puede mejorar pero esto es lo mas basico para q entiendas

Answer (score 0):

usa el principio de que si divides entre 2, puedes descartar a todos los pares solo queda probar impares, pero debes hacerlo desde 3 hasta la raíz del número

```
class Primos{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] primos=new int[80];
   primos[0]=2;
   int vacios=primos.length-1;
   boolean a;
   double j=2,k;
   while (vacios!=0){
     a=true;
     k=2;
     if(j%k!=0){// podra ser primo
       k++;
       while(a&&(k<=Math.sqrt(j))){
        if(j%k==0){
          a=false;//ya no es primo
        }else{
          k++;
        }
       }
    if(a){ //si no cambio es primo se agrega
      primos[primos.length-vacios]=(int)j;
    }
   }
   j++;
   vacios=0;
   for (int i=0;i<primos.length;i++) {
     if(primos[i]==0){
       vacios++;
     }
  }
}
/*imprimir el resultado*/
for (int i=0;i<primos.length;i++ ) {
System.out.printf("[%d]= %d \t",i+1,primos[i]);
 }
 }
}
```