# ¿como obtener los números primos de una matriz nxn?

Tags: java

No he podido aplicar el algoritmo para obtener los números primos en una matriz, me confundo.

```
    public void algoritmoSeleccion() {

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

            }

        }
    }
```

Esta el método básico, pero no encuentro bien la manera de aplicar el algoritmo a un array bidimensional.

La matriz es nxn y tiene números aleatorios.

Una mano, gracias. Se los agradecería.

Comment: De momento se ve que recorres la matriz, eso está bien. Ahora, que has pensado para comprobar si son primos? Dónde te falla? Pon lo que has intentado pero es muy sencillo lo que quieres

Comment: Hola MB0. Como te indica Pablo, has de intentarlo y mostrar donde te falla para que sobre eso podamos ayudarte. Ahora que tienes la iteracion por cada elemento de la matriz, implementa algo que detecte si es primo o no. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: El algoritmo se aplica a un número en concreto. Tienes que aplicárselo a cada número de ese array.

Comment: El problema es que no hallo la manera de comprobarlo para todos los números de la matriz, no se como establecer el limite.

Comment: Aca dejo una entrada donde se habla de validar números primos. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92452/primos-pares-e-impares-en-java/92909#92909

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void algoritmoSeleccion() {

for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            if(esPrimo(matriz[i][j]))  //Si es true, el valor es primo
        }

    }
}

public bool esPrimo(int num){
    for(int i=2; i<num/2; i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Lo que hacemos en esPrimo es comprobar si el número es primo o no. Para ello, comprobamos el resto de dividir dicho número por los menores hasta la mitad de su valor. Si al dividir por algún número su resto es 0 quiere decir que no es primo con lo cual devolvemos false, sino true.

Empezamos desde 2 porque todos números al dividirlos por 1 su resto es 0.

Lo he hecho mirando que los números de dentro de la matriz son enteros pero si son otro tipo lo puedes modificar en el valor que recibe la función esPrimo.

En if(esPrimo(matriz[i][j])) tienes que ver lo que quieres hacer con el valor.

Otra cosa, si siempre va a ser una matriz cuadrada puedes sustituir:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            if(esPrimo(matriz[i][j]))  //Si es true, el valor es primo
        }

    }
}
```

por:

```
int lon = matriz.length;
for (int i = 0; i < lon; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lon; j++) {
            if(esPrimo(matriz[i][j]))  //Si es true, el valor es primo
        }

    }
}
```