# Cómo hago un programa que verifique si un número es par o impar en Java usando if else?

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un programa en Java que me verifique si un número es par o impar, usando las sentencias if, else

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?, bienvenido por favor lee [ask], considera editar y agregar lo que lleves así como dudas puntuales pues al momento tu *pregunta* parece mas una petición y por ende terminaría cerrada

Comment: Puedes intentar dividiendo el numero que quieres verificar si es par o impar, si se puede dividir dentro de 2 y no te queda residuo, entonces es par, y si queda residuo, es impar! ;)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Primos, pares e impares en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92452/primos-pares-e-impares-en-java)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el operador '%'. Si tu tu numero n es par, al hacer n%2 el resultado será 0, y si es impar el resultado será 1.

```
if(n%2==0){
//codigo si es par
}else{
//codigo si es impar
}
```